# Getting typescript to throw an error on an instance of a union type which contains a set of properties inconsistent with every element of the union

Tags: typescript, types, union, strict

Suppose that I have

```js
type TYPE1 = { 
    id : number, 
    property1 : number 
}

type TYPE2 = { 
    id : number, 
    property2 : number
}
```

and

```js
type T = TYPE1 | TYPE2;
```

Is there a way of having typescript provide a warning or error if something like

```js
const t: T = { 
    id : 0, 
    property1 : 0, 
    property2 : 0
}
```

appears elsewhere in the code as it is neither of `TYPE1` nor `TYPE2`.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936